# Dji mavic python

Tags: python

у меня есть дрон dji mavic mini.
Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли под него разрабатывать всякие скрипты?
Другим словами, возможна ли для него разработка на python-dronekit?
Я просто только приобрёл данное устройство, не знаю как проверить.
Спасибо.